# How to use NLP in python to analyze questions from a chat conversation

Tags: python, nlp, chat, bots

I've written a chatbot in python which connects to discord, and is able to fulfil some tasks. One of the tasks is to query a list of resources of a specific computer game, and return the detailed location of the queried resource. 
Now I want to integrate the functionality into the chat, as seemlessly as possible. So I thought I could use NLP techniques for it.

To give an example:
User 1 wants to know where he/she can find the resource "wood". So he/she asks in the discord chat: "Where can I find wood?"

My program shall now be able to identify this question as a valid query for a resource location, and respond with the location for resource "wood".

This might involve several steps:

- Determine that in fact a *question* is asked
- Determine the name of the resource which was asked for
- ???

I am not new to programming, however I am new to NLP. Also I'm a beginner in deep learning / already developed RNN models using tensorflow/keras.

For this project, I found `nltk` and `spaCy`, both of which are python modules used for NLP. I've learned already that text analysis consists of several distinct jobs, and not all of them might be of interest for my project. But it seems that both tokenization and pos tagging might be of interest. But somehow I am struggling to find a viable approach for the task. It already starts with how to identify if a text message is *actually a question*. My research indicates this is no functionality which is provided by NLP libraries out of the box, and pre-trained deep learning models are usually used to categorize sentences like that.

Ideas I've had so far:

1) Analyze every chat message sentence by sentence
Tokenize the sentence, use stemming, then pos tagging, then iterate all tokens to find out if:

- The verbs "find" (Where can I find ...) or "get" (Where can I get ...)" or "is" (Where is ...) are contained
- Check if a noun is contained, and if so, if this noun is a valid resource name (a better approach would probably to find out of the noun is actually the object related to the verb. is this possible even?)
- Check if the sentence if a question by checking if the last token is a `?`

2) Use some kind of matching, like the `spaCy`'s rule based matching

- Build several patterns which can identify the desired question/question types
- Match the patterns on every chat message
- If matched, extract the resource name

3) Use non-NLP techniques
If everything else should be unviable/too complicated, I can still come up with a hardcoded approach where I would just pre-define a couple of question types, and string-search their occurence within chat messages, and try to manually extract the resource names by using string operations.
This will probably be the most error prone and unflexible solution, but I'll keep it as a fallback.

Of course, I do want to implement a solution which is working as flexible as possible, so it can detect various forms and types of questions, without hardcoding all possible types of questions beforehand. It should be as close to "the bot just understands the chat and answers the question" as possible.

Could someone guide me towards a good solution? (not asking for complete code, but rather the techniques/steps/libraries I shall use)

Maybe as a sidenote: In a later version I want to extend the functionality. Then, it shall be possible that other users name the location of a resource in the discord chat, and the bot shall add this location to its database, if its not already contained. So the chat conversation might look like:

```
User 1: Where can I find cryptonite?
User 2: It can be found in lex luthors lab
Bot: Shall I add "lex luthors lab" as location for resource "cryptonite"?
User 2: @bot: yes
Bot: Done.
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## tl:dr

It seems like you basically have an **intent**/**entity** problem.

1) Analyze every chat message sentence by sentence.
**This can be solved with intent classification.**

2) Use some kind of matching, like the spaCy's rule based matching
**This can be solved with entity extraction.**

---

## Intent

An intent is a classification of the whole sentence.

For example, you can have an intent: `find_resource`.
Then, you will need example sentences that should be classified as `find_resource`.
For example:

```
X = [
  'Where can I find wood?',
  'What is the location of wood?',
  'Where do I find fire?',
  'Give me the coordinates of lemons.',
  'What is the best place to gather coal?',
  'Do you know where I can find tomatoes?',
  'Tell me a spot to collect wood.'
]
```

You could train a neural network to perform this classification task, but there are much simpler models that you could try first. A good machine learning library is [scikit-learn](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/supervised_learning.html#supervised-learning) which provides out-of-the-box traditional machine learning classification methods. It also has a `feature_extraction.text` sub-package for dealing with text.

#### Example

```py
# Training data

## X is the sample sentences
X = [
    'Where can I find wood?',
    'What is the location of wood?',
    'Where do I find fire?',
    'Give me the coordinates of lemons.',
    'What is the best place to gather coal?',
    'Do you know where I can find tomatoes?',
    'Tell me a spot to collect wood.',
    'How can I level up strength?',
    'How do I train woodcutting?',
    'Where can I practice my swimming skill?',
    'Can I become better in running?',
    'Where can I train my woodcutting skill?'
]

## y is the intent class corresponding to sentences in X
y = [
    'find_resource',
    'find_resource',
    'find_resource',
    'find_resource',
    'find_resource',
    'find_resource',
    'find_resource',
    'improve_skill',
    'improve_skill',
    'improve_skill',
    'improve_skill',
    'improve_skill'
]

# Define the classifier

from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer
from sklearn.linear_model import SGDClassifier
from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline

clf = Pipeline(
    [
        ('tfidf', TfidfVectorizer()),
        ('sgd', SGDClassifier())
    ]
)

## Train the classifier

clf.fit(X, y)

# Test your classifier

## New sentences (that weren't in X and your model never seen before)

new_sentences = [
    'What are the coordinates of wood?',
    'Where can I find paper?',
    'How can I improve woodcutting?',
    'Where can I improve my jumping skill?'
]

predicted_intents = clf.predict(new_sentences)

print(predicted_intents)

> ['find_resource' 'find_resource' 'improve_skill' 'improve_skill']
```

---

## Entity Extraction

Entity Extraction is the task of finding a specific sub-string within your sentence. This can be `location`, `time`, `person_name`, etc... or in your case `resource_type`.

Typical training data looks like:

```
X = [
    'Where can I find [wood](resource_type)?',
    'What is the location of [wood](resource_type)?',
    'Where do I find [fire](resource_type)?',
    'How can I level up [strength](skill_type)?',
    'Where can I train my [woodcutting](skill_type) skill?'
]
```

Indeed [spaCy](https://spacy.io/usage/linguistic-features#named-entities) offers state of the art models. It has pre-trained entity types, but it also allows you to expand it with custom entities (`resource_type` in your case).

---

## Side note

```
User 1: Where can I find cryptonite?
User 2: It can be found in lex luthors lab
Bot: Shall I add "lex luthors lab" as location for resource "cryptonite"?
User 2: @bot: yes
Bot: Done.
```

You could model your problem as:

Intents:

```
X = [
  'Where can I find cryptonite?'
  'It can be found in lex luthors lab',
  'yes'
] 

y = [
  'find_resource',
  'provide_location',
  'affirm'
]
```

Entities:

```
X = [
  'Where can I find [cryptonite](resource_type)?'
  'It can be found in [lex luthors lab](location)',
  'yes'
]
```

The trick will be for you to figure out if `User 2` actually replied to `User 1` or not. Also, you need to keep the state of the conversation, but that is dependant on the bot framework that you are using. Nevertheless, it is not an NLP issue anymore.

Comment: First of all thanks for your great response. As proposed, I was able to train a SGDClassifier. I made it learn 3 categories: "find_resource", "find_resource_by_location" and "chat", where "chat" is just random/unrelated chat messages. I've created around 2000 sample questions, and also added another 1000 unrelated chat messages to train.
The result was pretty surprising for me: Verifiying with another 6000 random chat messages it successfully found resource queries of both types (even with structures I didnt have in training), and so far I could not find missing matches.

Comment: Regarding entity extraction: I think I will just string-search those, as I have a complete/known list of resource names, which I can look up in the chat messages. This will also enable me to process something like: "Does anyone know where I can find wood, stone and gold?".
So so far I am pretty happy with that solution. I have not used the SGD classifier before. I have only worked with sklearn's `LinearRegression`, and used several deep learning approaches. So also I have learned something new.
I was aware that I could not provide enough training data, but it seems to work out well currently

Comment: BTW I also found this: https://spacy.io/usage/examples#intent-parser Seems like its doing both the ob of intent classification and also entity extraction.
I wonder if this would perform even better? However it would surely be a pain to assemble a bigger dataset for training as every word needs to be labeled.

Comment: @user826955 glad you got something new from it. :D Indeed this spacy intent-parser will be more difficult to train because the training data it requires is really specific and more difficult to annotate. However, it would be able to figure out more complex sentences structures. Since you mentioned that the SGDClassifier is performing nearly at 100%, I don't see how much more it can be improved... ;)

Comment: Actually, it turned out that the classifier was not able to recognize all the sentences. It turned out that it could detect the questions, however depending on what resource was asked for. This is, I think, because my training sentences look like "Where do I find wood?", "Do you know where wood is?", "Does anyone know where I can find wood?". Now if someone asks for wood it will be detected perfectly, however if another resource is asked for, the classification fails.
This lead me to extend my traning set, to include all possible resource names. But  this way, the training data gros large.

Comment: My training sentences already contain a variety of sentence structures, and multiplying them by the number of resource names lead to a training set of around 120k for the type "find_resource". Of course, I need to add traning data for "normal" chat in contrast, so I had to find another 60-100k random chat messages (not containing any real resource query) to train the classifier for the other class ("chat" vs. "find_resource"). Note that the normal chat of course may also contain the resource names.

Comment: I am still a beginner in machine learning, so I dont know if I'm on the right way, or of my training data should be different. 
To reduce the number of training sentences, I added a random selection of resource names, so that I dont get num_sentences*num_resources, but I am still evaluating results, also comparing the performance to a trained CNN and RNN.